# Writing outside of the bounds of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c

Ive encountered a weird behaviour when writing to out of bounds indexes in a 2D array. When you run this code:

```
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int a[n][n];

   for (int i = 0; i < n + 5; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
         a[i][j] = j + i * n + 1;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("\n");
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
         printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
   }
```

what you get as a result becomes weirder and weirder as the dimensions of the array become larger (n = 4, 5 is interesting, for n = 7 it stops outputting anything at all). I'm gonna guess it's reliant on the compiler as to what the outputs will be so I'll paste mine here:

n = 4

```
  1  2  3  4
  7  8  9 10
 13 14 15 16
 19 20 21 22
```

n = 5

```
  1  2  3  4  5
  9 10 11 12 13
 17 18 19 20 21
 25 26 27 28 29
  5  5  56422104  4
```

My question is: what's happening in the background? How is the memory being allocated so that this happens?

Comment: How big is the array?

Comment: Please show how you're initializing the array, too. Either way, you're seeing Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Most likely, one of your out-of-bounds writes overwrote `a`, `i` or `j`. We can't see the memory allocation without a crystal ball or the assembly code of your program.

Comment: Here, I've added how it's declared as well.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior on writing outside the bounds of an array is *undefined*, meaning the language definition puts no requirements on the compiler or runtime environment to handle the situation in any particular way.  From the language's point of view, any result is equally correct, whether it's a core dump, corrupted data, or working without any apparent issue.

*Most likely*, the data you write to `a[i][j]` where `i >= n` is being overwritten by the calls to `printf` - you were writing into memory that later became part of `printf`'s stack frame, although there may be a different reason.